# mysql acces denied to user in localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I kind of locked myself out of mysql, don't know or remember how.
I have tried different things but no luck so far.
I have the **root** user who has all the privileges with the host **localhost**.
Like shown in the screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKFYF.jpg

When trying to connect from the computer where mysql is installed I get the message
**Access denied for user root@localhost**
Like shown in the screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt7S4.jpg

100% sure I have the right password, so It's not a password issue.

- MySQL version 5.1
- Windows Server 2008 R2

Any help on what could be the issue??
Thanks!

Comment: There are several resources for this already on the internet. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`.

Comment: I promise you, I tried that many times with no luck. Now suddenly it decides to work.Will accept your answer.

Comment: @Alex: That’s the default, so I’m going to assume you made a frustration typo in your password =D